# Optional parameters must appear after all requirements are met

Tags: c#

I am trying to debug some code that has a method CalculateTuition, and the one of the arguments is named credits. The error I am getting at run-time is, "Optional parameters must appear after all required parameters".
 The purpose of this application is to demonstrate that a method can be called with one, two or three arguments. I am unable to figure out the difference between the required parameters and the optional ones. Thank you for your time!

```
public static void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Tuition is {0}", Calculatetuition(15));
    Console.WriteLine("Tuition is {0}", CalculateTuition(15, 'O'));
    Console.WriteLine("Tuition is {0}", CalculateTuition(15, 'O', true));
}


public static double CalculateTuition(string code = "I", double credits,
         bool  scholarship = false)
{
    double tuition;
    const double RATE = 80.00;
    const double OUT_DISTRICT_FEE = 300.00;

    tuition = credits * RATE;
    if (code == 'I')
       tuition += OUT_DISTRICT_FEE;
    if (scholarship)
        tuition = 0;
    return tuition;
}
```

Comment: When you provide default value for parameter - it defined as "Optional". Optional parameters must be declared after all "required" parameters

Comment: Side note: this error can't happen at *run-time* with code shown - ether post is not showing real code or there is some confusion what "run-time" and "compile-time". You may also *consider* reading [Named and Optional arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static double CalculateTuition(string code = "I", double credits, bool  scholarship = false)
```

`code` is an optional argument here. If the caller does not provide a value for `code`, its default value will be `"I"`. However, as the error states, optional parameters must not be before required parameters. Change your method signature (and update usages accordingly) to:

```
public static double CalculateTuition(double credits, string code = "I", bool scholarship = false)
```

Or make `code` a required parameter

```
public static double CalculateTuition(string code, double credits, bool  scholarship = false)
```

Comment: Note that OP said "at run-time" - while your explanation is correct it does not address that strange part of the question.